# How to create my custom tslint rule set?

Tags: typescript, npm, tslint, code-standards

I want to introduce a typescript coding guideline that can be shared accross multiple projects. I don't want to copy paste a `tslint.json` over multiple times, it has happened currently and we have diverged version of it going around.

I want to base my guideline on `tslint:recommended`. And I see that the tslint syntax allows for `extend`, yet I am unclear about its usage and how to structure such a package.

Can such a project consists of merely a `tslint.json` itself or do I need to export a module?

I want the package to then be hosted on npm/sinopia instance, yet am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. You can create an NPM module that contains your rule set and can reference that in a `tslint.json` file's `extends` setting.

For example, you can create an NPM module named `my-rule-set` with this `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "my-rule-set",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "main": "my-rule-set.json"
}
```

and this `my-rule-set.json` (note that the `main` in the `package.json` references the `my-rule-set.json` file):

```
{
    "extends": "tslint:recommended",
    "rules":
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, with `my-rule-set` installed in `node_modules`, you can extend a `tslint.json` file with your own rule set:

```
{
    "extends": "my-rule-set"
}
```

There is more information on sharable configurations in [this TSLint blog post](http://palantir.github.io/tslint/2016/03/31/sharable-configurations-rules.html).

If your rule set contains only configurations of existing rules, that's all you need to do. However, if you intend to implement some custom rules, in `my-rule-set.json` you'll need to link to the directory where your custom rules are. So for example, it should also have something like: `"rulesDirectory": "./rules"`. Then the `./rules` directory should contain the compiled `.js` versions of your rules.

Comment: Great answer, just one more thing of note: in `my-rule-set.json` you'll need to link to the directory where your custom rules are. So for example, it should also have something like: `"rulesDirectory": "./rules"`.  Then the `./rules` directory should contain the _compiled_ `.js` versions of your rules.

(Feel free to edit this into your answer if you'd like @cartant)

Comment: @JKillian You may post it as an own answer, or if you think the change to be minor enough, edit this one yourself.

Comment: Updated the answer to include the `rulesDirectory` comment. (Thanks for your work on TSLint, @JKillian, it's a useful tool.)